# why can't I view my app on my aws ec2 instance? deployed with meteor up

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, meteor

I'm trying to get my meteor app up onto an aws ec2 instance using meteor up. 
This worked for me previously, following [this tutorial](http://sergelobatch.com/slog/2015/4/10/using-mup/). 
I've successfully run `mup setup` and `mup deploy`, but when I try to access the app through the Public DNS, I get

> Google Chrome's connection attempt to
>   ec2-52-######.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com was rejected. The
>   website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

When I ssh it works fine, there seems to be an issue related to port 80.
I've tried running `telnet 52.###### 80`, to get `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`.

When I set up the instance, I had ports 80 and 22 open in my security group. Since then I've also added "all traffic".

When I ssh into the server then run `netstat -nlp` , i get:

```
ubuntu@ip-#########:~$ netstat -nlp
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18210           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::47267                :::*                                -               
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     7466     -                   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6668     -                   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8353     -                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8670     -                   /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     137001   -                   /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Any advice on what I should try next would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your application actually listening on port 80?

Comment: Did you reserve an Elastic IP and assign it to your instance? If not, the public IP that the instance starts with will change on reboots.

Comment: EEAA, I tried to check if it was listening not sure if I did so correctly because I am a noob, I don't think it's listening on port 80. Also I've rebooting the instance, but I'll try rebooting again

Comment: tomstephens89 I reboot the instance, it's up and running again, but the public ip has not changed, and I still can't access the app through the public dns. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, from your netstat output, nothing is listening on port 80. So there's yer problem.

Comment: just adding for information: a simple reboot will not change the public IP address. a stop/start will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `netstat` output indicates that your application is not listening on port 80.